# MVC Partial view having more than one model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, razor

I have a tree structure of objects (as in picture below). Classes `Descendant1` and `Descendant2` are to be viewed in the same way as `Form` class(the root class). I wanted to create a partial view for that, however,  I need to have a model in the view as I am using properties from the model(such as Name from the root class)

[image: structure of classes]

This is my code of FormView that is to be in the partial view:

```
<div>
   @foreach (var subForm in Model.SubForms)
{
    Html.RenderPartial(partialView, subForm);
}
<div>@Model.Name</div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if it was possible to create a partial view that can have multiple models? Do I create one controller for all the descendant classes together? Otherwise, do you have any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Create a public proxy class that has the models you want in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if it was possible to create a partial view that can have multiple models?

Yes, make a view model for those 3 classes. Example below is named `FormViewModel`.

```
public class FormViewModel{
   public class Descendant1 {get;set;}
   public class Descendant2 {get;set;}
   public class Descendant3 {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your view you could do;

```
@foreach (var subForm in Model.SubForms)
{
   FormViewModel fmv = new FormViewModel();

   // access its class properties
   fmv.Descendant1.SubForms.Add(new Form(){ // assign properties });

   // pass the view model to the partial view
   Html.RenderPartial(partialView, fmv);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Helped me solve my problem :) . There is only one thing: `public class Descendant1 {get;set;}` in your example should probably be `public Descendant1  desc1 {get;set;}`.